# Avoiding false sharing of SPSC queue indices

Tags: c++, concurrency, atomic, lock-free, false-sharing

Let's imagine a lock-free concurrent SPSC (single-producer / single-consumer) queue.

- The **producer thread** **reads** `head`, `tail`, `cached_tail` and **writes** `head`, `cached_tail`.
- The **consumer thread** **reads** `head`, `tail`, `cached_head` and **writes** `tail`, `cached head`.

Note, that `cached_tail` is accessed only by the producer thread, just like `cached_head` is accessed only by the consumer thread. They can be thought as private thread local variables, so they are unsynchronized, thus not defined as atomic.

The data layout of the queue is the following:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cstddef>
#include <thread>

struct spsc_queue
{
    /// ...

    // Producer variables
    alignas(std::hardware_destructive_interference_size) std::atomic<size_t> head; // shared
    size_t cached_tail; // non-shared

    // Consumer variables
    alignas(std::hardware_destructive_interference_size) std::atomic<size_t> tail; // shared
    size_t cached_head; // non-shared

    std::byte padding[std::hardware_destructive_interference_size - sizeof(tail) - sizeof(cached_head)];
};
```

Since I want to avoid **false sharing**, I aligned `head` and `tail` to the L1 cache line size.

The pseudo-code-ish implementation of the `push`/`pop` operations is the following:

```
bool push(const void* elems, size_t n)
{
    size_t h = atomic_load(head, relaxed);

    if (num_remaining_storage(h, cached_tail) < n)
    {
        cached_tail = atomic_load(tail, acquire);

        if (num_remaining_storage(h, cached_tail) < n)
            return false;
    }

    // write from elems

    atomic_store(head, h + n, release);
    return true;
}

bool pop(void* elems, size_t n)
{
    size_t t = atomic_load(tail, relaxed);

    if (num_stored_elements(cached_head, t) < n)
    {
        cached_head = atomic_load(head, acquire);

        if (num_stored_elements(cached_head, t) < n)
            return false;
    }

    // read to elems

    atomic_store(tail, t + n, release);
    return true;
}

void wait_and_push(const void* elems, size_t n)
{
    size_t h = atomic_load(head, relaxed);

    while (num_remaining_storage(h, cached_tail) < n)
        cached_tail = atomic_load(tail, acquire);

    // write from elems

    atomic_store(head, h + n, release);
}

void wait_and_pop(void* elems, size_t n)
{
    size_t t = atomic_load(tail, relaxed);

    while (num_stored_elements(cached_head, t) < n)
        cached_head = atomic_load(head, acquire);

    // write to elems

    atomic_store(tail, t + n, release);
}
```

At initialization (not listed here), all the indices are set to `0`.
The functions `num_remaining_storage` and `num_stored_elements` are `const` functions performing simple calculations based on the passed arguments and the immutable queue capacity - they do not perform any atomic reads or writes.

**Now the question is**: do I need to align `cached_tail` and `cached_head` as well to completely avoid false sharing any of the indices, or it is okay as it is. Since `cached_tail` is producer private, and `cached_head` is consumer private, I think `cached_tail` can be in the same cache line as `head` (producer cache line), just like `cached_head` in the same cache line as `tail` (consumer cache line) without false sharing to ever happen.

Am I missing something?

Comment: FWIW, I'm pretty sure you don't need to align the cached values, but didn't get enough conviction yet.

Comment: You're probably going to want 3 cache lines: writer-only, reader-only, and stuff accessed by both.  Ideally you can avoid having both threads write the shared line frequently.  Even one writing and the other reading keeps flipping it from Modified to Shared and requiring the thread doing a store to do an RFO to regain exclusive ownership.  But having the non-shared vars in separate cache lines could allow a bit more progress to be made / in-flight while waiting on those share requests or RFOs.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't entirely understand your comment. Do you suggest to put both `cached_tail` and `cached_head` into a common, but third cache line? Even if they are not shared across threads, they are handled by different threads (`cached_tail` by the producer, `cached_head` by the consumer). Look at the beginning of my question at the access patterns.

Comment: I should have said "producer only" / "consumer only" / stuff accessed by both. Obviously variables that are only accessed by one of the threads should go in a cache line that the other thread never touches. IDK if you thought I was saying to break it down by write-only vs. read-only data?  No, I meant writer = producer. Anyway, the hard question is how to split up other variables that are actually shared, and whether there's anything to gain or lose from having more lines so you can have vars that only the producer writes (read by consumer) in a line that the producer can always at least read.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, okay, it's clear now. Well, `head` and `cached_tail` are always updated together in `push()` - just like `tail` and `cache_head` in `pop()`. But `head` and `tail` are accessed by both threads. At the worst case I can use four cache lines, one for each. According to your suggestion `head` and `tail` should go to the same cache line, since they are accessed by both threads. That would definitely cause false sharing. I don't think it is a good idea, also all lock-free implementation I've seen put them (`head` and `tail`) into separate cache lines.

Comment: @PeterCordes What's the problem with the current 2 cache lines version?

Comment: `push` has to *modify* `cached_tail`, but `pop` will sometimes read `head` in that same line, taking it out of MESI Modified state.  Your caching strategy makes that infrequent so it may be fine or at least not worth another extra cache line.  Re: `head` and `tail` in the same line: I didn't think that through fully, or I was for some reason thinking of a linked-list implementation where pop detects empty via a NULL pointer in a node instead of by looking at the producer's state.  So yes, as I eventually got to saying, it's a question of how to split up the vars that both threads R and/or W.

Comment: Oh, and in the fast path `push` only reads `cached_tail`, and that's still fast with the line in MESI Shared state.  So yes this is probably good.  If the queue is near-empty most of the time then contention is unavoidable and separate cache lines for the fully private `cached_tail` and `cached_head` are unlikely to help.  Although they *might*?  Also if we're lucky, the compiler can keep the cached head / tail in a register if called inside a fairly tight loop that doesn't inline too much other stuff.

Comment: @PeterCordes Haha, that was a typo. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for providing the pseudocode - it is still lacking some details, but I think I get the basic idea. You have a bounded SPSC queue where the indexes can wrap around, and you use the `cached_tail` variable in `push` to check if there are free slots, so you can avoid loading `tail` from a potentially invalidated cache line (and vice versa for `pop`).

I would suggest to put `head` and `cached_tail` next to each other (i.e., on the same cache line), and `tail` and `cached_head` on a different one. `push` *always* reads *both* variables - `head` and `cached_tail`, so it makes sense to have them close together. `cached_tail` is only updated if there are no more free slots and we have to reload `tail`.

Your code is a bit thin on details, but it seems that there is some room for optimization:

```
bool push(const void* elems, size_t n)
{
    size_t h = atomic_load(head);

    if (num_remaining_storage(h, cached_tail) < n)
    {
        auto t = atomic_load(tail);
        if (t == cached_tail)
          return false;

       // we only have to update our cached_tail if the reloaded value
       // is different - and in this case it is guaranteed that there
       // is a free slot, so we don't have to perform a recheck.
        cached_tail = t;
    }

    // write from elems

    atomic_store(head, h + n);
    return true;
}
```

That way `cached_tail` is only ever updated when `head` is also updated, so this is another reason for them to be on the same cache line. Of course the same kind of optimization can be applied to `pop` as well.

That is exactly why I wanted to see some code, because the *access pattern* is crucial to determine which variables should share a cache line and which should not.

Comment: Good idea with delaying update of `cached_tail` or `cached_head`.  That removes any possible benefit to having 4 separate cache lines.  (Without that I was wondering if it made any sense to split them up so spinning on a retry of push or pop isn't writing the line the other thread needs to write.  In a full or empty queue situation.)  Even then I'm not sure it's significant.  If the line is in Shared state the other thread could read it more easily, but would still have to RFO on the store anyway, whether we invalidate it again after their read or not.

Comment: (I think that same optimization can work for `pop`, or at least a similar one.)

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, of course the same optimization can be applied for `pop` too. I did want to mentioned that, but apparently forgot. Thanks for the note, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Great answer and idea on the further optimization! I updated my answer with some more details, including memory ordering and waiting versions of `push` and `pop` (`wait_and_push`, `wait_and_pop`). If you have any more suggestions about them, don't hesitate to share with me. ;]

Comment: I think I could use the same optimization you suggested to the spinwait versions as well.

Comment: "we only have to update our cached_tail if the reloaded value is different" - this is only true when `n == 1`, otherwise it only means that there is more space, but after the re-load it can be still not enough for `n`, so re-testing the condition `num_remaining_storage(h, cached_tail) < n` is required if `n > 1`. Still, it is a great optimization when `n == 1`. I have separate functions for batch (bulk) and single-value operations so there is no need for extra branches.

Comment: Yes you are right, I did not realize from your pseudocode that you want to perform bulk operations. However, I don't think that this optimization works for the blocking functions, since you are actually waiting for head/tail to be updated. FWIW: the memory orderings look fine.

Comment: @mpoeter There is a short chat about the blocking functions here, if you are interested (the point is that the delayed assignment of the cached indices is still advantageous in this case): https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212865/room-for-plasmacel-and-peter-cordes

Comment: Ah, yes you can of course avoid repeated writes to the cached values. In fact I would use a local variable to track the index and only write to the cached variable just once when there is enough space to proceed s Peter Codes already suggested.